# Windows Authentication in ASP.NET checking for a specific user security group

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I’m creating a general information portal in an Active Directory/IIS/ASP.NET 4.5 environment. Among other things, the portal will link to multiple personnel request forms depending on which entity it’s for (casino vs. the tribe outside the casino). I’ve started with the casino’s request form and after getting the email submission working I’m to the point now where I’m working on authentication. Everything’s laid out using a master page for what it matters.

My plan for authenticating the user is to use Windows authentication to check the user logged into the workstation and then to check if the user belongs to a particular Security group we’ve set up specifically for people to be able to access the request form. Note that I don’t want to lock the entire site down, but rather individual pages on the site. Also, people who can access the casino’s request form shouldn’t be able to access the general tribal request form and vice versa.

I’ve seen several ways to accomplish things like this but none of them seem to quite work for what I’m doing. After being advised to use Trace.Warn() rather than Console.WriteLine() I’ve managed to get the page to check the identity of the logged in user, which I see in the trace results. However, I’m running into a roadblock with getting it to check the user’s groups at all, much less check among them to see if they belong to the specific group that should be able to see the page. What’s the best way for me to do this?

Comment: Show your code so we can see how you're trying to check the group. Or at least provide the framework so we can see what the method signatures should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use *Windows Authentication* directly and want to secure to a group a user belongs to, it's pretty simple if you use *web.config* and separate directories for each different security levels.

Simply place the request forms into separate sub directories instead of into the same one.

You would setup a directory structure for your web application such as this

```
My web application root
|__ web.config
   |__ Sub directory1
      |__ web.config
   |__ Sub directory2
      |__ web.config
```

Within the *web.config* in your web application root, you could grant more access and the groups *Secure group 1, Secure group 2, Secure group 3* would be able to see pages in the root.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Secure group 1, Secure group 2, Secure group 3" />
        <deny users="*, ?" />
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Now under *Sub directory1*, you could limit this to *Secure group 1* and prevent any others

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Secure group 1" />
        <deny users="*, ?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And so on. Any pages within this subdirectory would not be viewable to users without that group.

It becomes much more involved if you want to look up group membership directly and denying it in code.

**To enable Windows Authentication** (in IIS)

Go to IIS Manager and open Authentication for your Web Application

[image]

Disable other authentication methods except for Windows Authentication

[image]

Comment: Doesn't <allow roles="Group" /> require database setup? That's something I'm trying to avoid having to deal with at this stage.

Comment: Not if you use _Windows Authentication_. The database part normally comes in when you're using ASP.NET membership and Forms Authentication

Comment: I've added a quick overview of doing this in IIS.

Comment: All right! It worked. This was a much better solution in the long run than bloating my root web.config file with <location path=file.aspx"> tags and replicating all the information, having to change it in every block if I changed it anywhere.